# Popping the last element of a one-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

When it comes to `list`s, we all know and love good old `pop`, which removes the last item from the list and returns it:

```
>>> x = range(3)
>>> last_element = x.pop()
>>> last_element
2
>>> x
[0, 1]
```

But suppose I'm using a one-dimensional `numpy` `array` to hold my items, because I'm doing a lot of elementwise computations.  What then is the most efficient way for me to achieve a `pop`?

Of course I can do

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(3)
>>> last_element = x[-1]
>>> x = np.delete(x, -1)  # Or x = x[:-1]
>>> last_element
2
>>> x
array([0, 1])
```

And, really, when it comes down to it, this is fine.  But is there a one-liner for arrays I'm missing that removes the last item and returns it at the same time?

And I'm not asking for

```
>>> last_element, x = x[-1], x[:-1]
```

I'm not counting this as a one-liner, because it's two distinct assignments achieved by two distinct operations. Syntactic sugar is what puts it all on one line.  It's a sugary way to do what I've already done above.  (Ha, I was sure someone would rush to give this as the answer, and, indeed, someone has.  This answer is the equivalent of my asking, "What's a faster way to get to the store than walking?"  and someone answering, "Walk, but walk faster."  Uh . . . thanks.  I already know how to walk.)

Comment: Why is `pop` useful for elementwise computations?  Why not iteration?  Or stick with the lists that you know and love?

Comment: @hpaulj i don't think i said that `pop` was useful for elementwise computations.  i happen to be doing a lot of elementwise computations (hence the utility of arrays) and, independently, happen to need to pop elements into and out of my array.  the elements of my array are neuron membrane potentials, and every time a neuron spikes, i pop it from the end of the array and stick it onto the front.

Comment: You mean something like `np.roll(np.arange(10),1)`?  It, in effect, does `x.take(np.concatenate([[9],range(0,9)]))`.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, i guess, except it's a little more complicated for me.  i pop the last value, do some elementwise computations on the array sans that value, then pop a different value to the front, then do more elementwise computations, and so on.

Comment: How about a roll, followed by vector operations on a view: `x[1:]`.  You might be by with 1 array copy per cycle rather than 2.

Comment: @hpaulj hmm, yeah, that might work.  many thanks.

Comment: I just realized that `x[:-1]` is also a view.  But pulling a value out of the middle is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such one liner for `numpy` (unless you write your own).  `numpy` is meant to work on fixed sized objects (or objects that change less frequently).  So by that metric a regular old `python` `list` is better for popping.

You are correct in that element-wise operations are better with `numpy`.  You're going to have to profile out your code and see which performs better and make a design decision.

Comment: great answer, but your reasoning that "`numpy` is meant to work on fixed sized objects" doesn't work here.  `numpy` includes `delete` and `insert` functions for arrays -- functions that change an array's size -- so why not `pop`?

Comment: It is written to allow changes to their objects (via `delete` and `insert`) but `numpy` is not optimized well for constantly changing the size of your array for example.  A python list will do that better.  When I say "fixed size objects" I meant objects that don't OFTEN change in their memory allocation.  i.e. a matrix or array that doesn't change size often, but you may want to do many operations on it or with it

Comment: i agree, but, again, this doesn't explain the absence of `pop`.  `pop` doesn't imply "constantly changing" an array, any more than `delete` or `insert` does.

Comment: No but `delete` and `insert` are more general,  they allow for you to change the object in many different ways.  And in the python notion of "only having one way to do it", the authors of `numpy` (I assume) decided that there wasn't enough need for a `pop` given the rarity of its likely use with `numpy` objects.  Ultimately I can't perfectly explain why it doesn't exist in `numpy`, I didn't write it, I can only speculate

Comment: ah, yes, this is the reason.  that makes sense.  you're right: `delete` and `insert` are more general.  the general version of `pop` would `pop` dimensions of a multi-dimensional array, and that's weird.

Comment: Look at the code for `delete` and `insert`.  Both are Python 4+ screens long. They do exactly the kind of assignments that you are trying avoid.  They don't change an array's size.  They make new arrays using indexing and/or concatenation.

Comment: The 'only one way' philosophy applies more to the core Python code.  `numpy` historically is the merger of several numeric packages.  And functions like `append`, `insert` and `delete` are probably late addons, conveniences for programmers who are more familiar with lists.